# Filtering a query without having to write in the full name in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a form in Microsoft Access with a textbox and a query. Whatever is written in the textbox will be shown in the query (for example you type customer1 and the query displays all rows that have firstname(this is a column name) customer 1).
Now I'm just trying to make it so that you don't have to write the full name of the customer in order to have the query filter the table.
For example : I have customers named Jhon, Edward and Mark, but in order to display only Mark I have to write in "Mark"(the full name). I want it to be able to filter out all customers with for example first two letters of their name "Ma" when I write "Ma" in the textbox.

Here is the code that I've been using to filter everything so far :

```
SELECT * FROM Kupci   
WHERE Forms.[Form1].[Text4] IS NULL 
OR 
(
     Forms.[Form1].[Text4] = Forms.[Form1].[Text4] 
AND  Ime=Forms.[Form1].[Text4]
);
```

Side-Note : Kupci means customers and ime means first name. Also the query displays everything if there is no text in the textbox.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a specific form by clicking on a specific cell or row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160452/how-to-open-a-specific-form-by-clicking-on-a-specific-cell-or-row)

Comment: Have you tried `Like Forms.[Form1].[Text4] & "*" ` ?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the following is what you want:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Kupci   
WHERE Forms.[Form1].[Text4] IS NULL 
OR Ime LIKE Forms.[Form1].[Text4] & "*"
```

If that query you had searched for whole names, this should do partial names.

Comment: Thank you that was just what I was looking for it works now.